# Запятая перед "плюс"

Tags: пунктуация

Нередко в тексте мы вместо союза И употребляем слово "плюс": "Мне нужно найти три рекламных объявления(,) плюс согласовать тексты к ним". Если на "плюс" распространяются правила относительно союза И, то запятая тут не нужна, но интонационно она просится. А если идет простое перечисление: "У меня есть сто рублей(,) плюс десять долларов". Как быть тут? Какие правила распространяются на "плюс" и какой частью речи оно является? Союзом, как и И?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря: Слово ПЛЮС (неизм.) может употребляться в разговорном стиле в значении наречия "с прибавлением чего-либо", например: Оплата железнодорожных билетов плюс командировочные.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

1. Слово ПЛЮС может заменять союз И, при этом мы имеем словосочетание, где значение соединения выполняет предлог С: "У меня есть сто рублей плюс десять долларов".
2. Слово ПЛЮС может выполнять роль структурного элемента, поясняющего семантику, но не влияющего на формальную грамматику: Мне нужно найти три рекламных объявления, плюс согласовать тексты к ним". Дополнительный структурный элемент "плюс" перед однородным сказуемым обозначает его присоединительный характер (в значении союза А ТАКЖЕ).

ПРИМЕРЫ

Основа "реанимации" ― витамин B3 плюс интенсивные банные процедуры.

Сегодня, спустя несколько лет, оригинальная ресторанная сеть насчитывает более 100 заведений в Великобритании, плюс рестораны в Нью-Йорке, Токио и Гонконге.